# findとxargsを利用したgrepでマッチしたファイルをパスで絞り込む方法

Tags: linux, command-line

現在、ファイルネームを`find`コマンドで絞り込み、パイプで`xargs grep`して中身を検索したあとに、さらにその出力結果を、パスで絞り込むために、さらにパイプで`grep`を繋いでいます。しかし、この方法は同じようなコマンドを二度使っているのでちょっと冗長で、もう少しいい方法がないかと考えています。

具体的には以下のようなコマンドです:

```
$ find . -name "*.rb" | xargs grep "HogeHoge" | grep "app"
```

`find`の使い方がこなれていないのも、上のように冗長になる要因ではあるかとは思いますが、できることなら`grep`の何らかのオプションで出来る方法があれば教えて下さい。あるいは、この発想自体が筋が悪く、`find`で対象パスを絞り込むべきならば、その方法を教えてください。

Comment: いまいち意図が分かりづらいのですが、"app"がファイル名に含まれているものだけに絞り込みたいということですか?

Comment: その通りです。`find . -name "*.rb" | xargs grep "HogeHoge"`をすると、`HogeHoge`で引っかかったファイルパスとそのライン番号が出るかと思われます。このときに出力されたファイル名で絞り込みをかけたいというのが質問の趣旨になります

Comment: すみません、ファイル内に"... HogeHoge app ..." という行があった場合、それも引っかかってしまうと思いますが、そうではないのですよね？

Comment: 確かに自分の例示コマンドが悪かったですね……。あくまでも`grep "app"`の部分はパス名を絞りこむために利用しているものであって、`HogeHoge app`みたいなものにマッチすることは、今回の質問の趣旨からは外れます

Comment: command-lineのタグを追加しました。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

※ すっかり勘違いをしていました。

```
$ find . -type f -regex ".*app.*\.rb" | xargs grep 'HogeHoge'
```

でしょうか？ 念の為、ディレクトリを grep しない様に `-type f` を find に付けておいた方が良いかと思います。

追記 0:

※ 追記ばかり多くてすみません

`-path`, `-name` オプションと GNU find の `-regex` オプションの違いですが、

```
$ find . -type f -regex ".*app.*\.rb"
  => ./app/a.rb            # Match
  => ./xyz/application.rb  # Match
  => ./application1.rb     # Match
$ find . -type f -path "*app*/*" -name "*.rb"
  => ./app/a.rb            # Match
  => ./xyz/application.rb  # Not match
  => ./application1.rb     # Not match
```

となります。質問者である esehara さんの目的次第になりますが、`-regex` オプションではディレクトリ名でもファイル名でも "app" という文字列が含まれているファイル全てにマッチしてしまいます。必要に応じて使い分けると良いかと思います。
なお、`-regex` オプションのない find コマンドで同じ動作をさせたい場合は、以下の様になります。

```
$ find . -type f \( -path "*app*/*" -name "*.rb" \) -o -name "*app*.rb"
```

ちなみに、GNU find には `-iregex` というオプションがあって、これは大文字か小文字であるかを無視します(case insensitive)。同様に `-iname` や `-ilname` オプションも用意されています。

追記 その1:

おそらく、`-regex` は GNU find だけにあるオプションかと思います。

> GNU find(1)
>
> -regex pattern
>
> File name matches regular expression pattern. This is a match on the whole path, not a search. For example, to match a file named `./fubar3', you can use the regular expression `.*bar.' or `.*b.*3', but not `f.*r3'. The regular expressions understood by find are by default Emacs Regular Expressions, but this can be changed with the -regextype option.

追記 その2:

fumiyas さんの、

> ファイル名に空白などが含まれていても安全です。

について、xargs を使う場合には、find に `-print0` と xargs に `-0` オプションも付けます。ただし、どちらとも GNU 拡張です。

```
$ find . -type f -regex ".*app.*\.rb" -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'HogeHoge'
```

余談ですが、`zero(NULL) option` は GNU tools の幾つかに導入されています。

> GNU grep(1)
>
> -z, --null-data
>
> Treat the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline. Like the -Z or --null option, this option can be used with commands like sort -z to process arbitrary file names.

例えば、この `-ｚ` オプションを使うとテキストファイル全体を単一な論理行とみなして検索を行います。以下は単純なウェブスクレイピングの例です。

```
$ wget -q -O - http://news.tv-asahi.co.jp/news_politics/articles/000041338.html |
  nkf -w |
  grep --binary-files=text --null-data -Po '(?<=<p>)([\s\S]+?\s*)(?=</p>)'
```

Answer (score 2):

find の後で絞り込むのが良いと思います。

```
$ find . -name "*.rb" | grep "app" | xargs grep "HogeHoge"
```

もしくは grep の検索結果の **ファイル名部分だけ** にマッチさせて

```
$ find . -name "*.rb" | xargs grep "HogeHoge"| grep '^[^:]*app'
```

とするのが良いです。(`:` が出て来ない文字が続いて app がマッチします)
尚、この方法は Windows だとドライブレター`C:\`とマッチする場合もありますのでご注意下さい。

Answer (score 2):

`find`(1) は様々な条件で対象ファイルを絞りこむことが可能ですので、一通りマニュアルをご覧になることをお勧めします。条件のほかに条件の AND (`-a` オプション。省略可能)、OR (`-o` オプション)、グループ化 (`(` と `)` で括る。シェルから実行する場合は `\(` のように要エスケープ) も可能です。

「ディレクトリ名に `app` が含まれる `*.rb` ファイルのうち `HogeHoge` にマッチする行を含むファイルのパス名と該当行を表示する」という要件であれば、`find` や `grep` の実装に依存しない (GNU などに依存しない) コマンドラインの例は次のようになります。

```
$ find . -type f -path "*app*/*" -name "*.rb" -exec grep "HogeHoge" /dev/null {} +
```

このコマンドラインなら GNU などに依存せず、`xargs` も不要で、かつファイル名に空白などが含まれていても安全です。ただし、とても古い OS の `find` だと `-exec` オプション中の `+` に対応していないものがあるので要注意です。また、`-path` オプションが対応していないものもあります。

`-path` に対応していない `find` の場合は、ほかの回答のように別途 `grep` などでフィルターする必要があります。

```
$ find . -type f -name "*.rb" |grep "app.*/" |xargs grep "HogeHoge" /dev/null
```

これだとパス名に空白文字が含まれている場合にうまく動きませんが、大抵は問題ないでしょう。

`/dev/null` は、条件にマッチするファイルが一つしか存在しなかった場合にも該当ファイルの名前を出力するためのハックです。GNU `grep` など、`-H` (`--with-filename`) オプションがない `grep` 実装で有効な方法です。

Comment: 質問欄の例を見ますと、ファイルパスに "app" が含まれている、と読めます。"-name"オプションを使いますと、例えば「.../app/a.rb」ファイルにマッチしないと思われます。

Comment: おお、なるほど。見直しを検討します…。ありがとうございます。